# combine multiple for loop scripts in a single bash script

Tags: bash, unix

I want to combine two for loop scripts in a single script. Each script is not related to the other.
Let's say there are two files.

- file1
- file2

I want to write a script like

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `cat file1` ; do
    command 1
    command 2
done

for j in `cat file2` ; do
    command 1
    command 2
done
```

Comment: What stops you from doing this?

Comment: What's the problem ?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 0):

In my answer I will use the notation `$(cat file1)`, which is a nice way the call a subprocess (backtics become confusing).
When you want to loop j for each value of i, combine the loops with

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat file1); do
   for j in $(cat file2); do
      command_1
      command_2
   done 
done
```

I think you want to combine the loops differently: call the same commands for everything in both files. This can be done with

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat file1) $(cat file2); do
   command_1
   command_2
done
```

In this case, the two `cat` commands  can be combined:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat file1 file2); do
   command_1
   command_2
done
```

The above script is doing very little with the value of `i`. Your commands are called for each word in the files file1 and file2. I think you want to call the commands for each line in these files, that can be done differently:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat file1 file2 | while read -r line; do
   command_1 "${line}"
   command_2 "${line}"
done
```

When you use this for other cases, please remember that you can also `read` to split each line in words and when you only have have one inputfile you can do without the `cat`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat file1 file2 > file3
while read -r var1 var2 othervars; do
   command_1 "${var1}"
   command_2 "${var2}"
   echo "The remaining words ${othervars} are not used in this loop."
done < file3
```